# Editing file geodatabase while other users read/view it gives ERROR 000224

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, editing, file-geodatabase, lock

Is there way to edit data within a file geodatabase while other user read/view data only. I deployed a file geodatabase and other users view the data but my process scripts can not edit the data and gives me ERROR 000224 cannot acquire a lock.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Not really. The locks are there to prevent horrific crashes during read when the data changes. Normally, that's the job of the RDBMS, but file geodatabase doesn't *have* an RDBMS.

Comment: I found information suggesting that  if I share the geodatabase folder as read-only I can edit it while others read. It is at the end of the page https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabases-and-windows-explorer.htm . However this method did not work for me

Comment: Network shares cut file geodatabase performance in half. At that point you might be better off using binary replicas.

Comment: @Vince Thanks! I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, In file geodatabase feature classes create lock files as soon as anyone accesses the same.

We do not have multiple edit capability, even though other users have just added the feature class for viewing, the edits will fail because of lock file generated.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer